# Euclidean space problem

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

In three-dimensional space, is it true that if you take line $a$ of a plane and line $b$ of the plane perpendicular to the first one, then the angle between line $a$ and $b$ (at which they intersect) is $90^o$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Suppose the two planes are the $x$-$y$ plane and the $x$-$z$-plane in the usual coordinate system.  So they are perpendicular.  But you can take in each plane a line that is very close to the $x$-axis.  the angle between these two lines will be very small.